# I used "git clean" command and it has whipped my Mac to its original settings

Tags: git

Can anyone help me? I have no idea what is going on. I was able to commit to my github normally. Then this happened. I have never seen untracked files.

```
@Nicolass-MBP js-learning % git status
warning: could not open directory 'Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/': Operation not permitted
warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    modified:   ../.DS_Store
    modified:   ../.zsh_history
    modified:   ../Desktop/.DS_Store
    modified:   ../Desktop/Random/.DS_Store
    modified:   ../Desktop/Random/etc/.DS_Store
    deleted:    ../Desktop/Screen Shot 2022-10-03 at 5.23.09 AM.png
    modified:   ../Landing-Page (modified content)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../.zsh_sessions/041416EF-5519-45E5-AC5E-7E96E733EC55.history
    ../.zsh_sessions/041416EF-5519-45E5-AC5E-7E96E733EC55.session
    ../.zsh_sessions/06D1E636-94B2-4BB2-BB46-F960059470C6.history
    ../.zsh_sessions/06D1E636-94B2-4BB2-BB46-F960059470C6.session
    ../.zsh_sessions/3C800BCB-DDDA-4364-A94B-2455E28A3B14.historynew
    ../.zsh_sessions/42CEB35D-E22A-41A7-8A3F-291A54F11066.history
    ../.zsh_sessions/42CEB35D-E22A-41A7-8A3F-291A54F11066.session
    ../Desktop/Screenshot 2022-11-07 at 3.46.03 PM.png
    ../Library/
    ../Music/
    ../css-odin-hw/
    ../html-boilerplate/
    ./
    ../new-user-singup/
    ../odin-recipes/
    ../repos/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: can you check the content of you `js-learning` directory ? `ls -lA js-learning/`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have created a git repository in your home directory.  Check if there is a folder called `.git` in there:

```
ls -d ~/.git
```

If so, you will probably need to start your repository over and make sure you initialize it in a directory that houses ONLY the things that you want under version control (presumably the things in the `js-learning` folder):

```
# keep it aside, but prevent git to treat your home directory as a repository
mv ~/.git ~/.git.bak

cd ~/js-learning
git init
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not see a folder called  .git                            
This is what I got 

@Nicolass-MBP js-learning % ls ~/.git
COMMIT_EDITMSG ORIG_HEAD description hooks  info  objects  refs
HEAD  config  gc.log  index  logs  packed-refs

Comment: Yes, it's there. You see its content. To see the very directory: `ls -d ~/.git`